# Joomla Template Override for newest Article of Category

Tags: php, sql, templates, joomla, joomla1.6

Guys, 
I've got an problem... I am using an alternative layout for articles in a certain category. 
My aim is to display an extra div (with an background-image) for the Newest article of the category. And this should only effect the newest article.

So, as I am not familiar with the Joomla-API. I would now like to know what's the best way to determine (in PHP/MySQL/whatever) if an article is the newest article of its category?

Thanks for a reply (Btw. I am using J1.6)

Ripei

Answer (score 1):

This code should do the trick

```
    $db=& JFactory::getDBO();
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM #__content ORDER BY created DESC';
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $showcat = $db->loadObjectList();
```

Comment: this looks like a very useful snippet of code. I will give it a try, after I have resolved why my layout-override does not work: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5795799/joomla-custom-template-override-not-working

Answer (score 1):

when you say you already use an alternative layout, do you display the articles in chronological order (newest first, see the corresponding menu item properties)? Then you could add a counter to the loop which calls the article view and display an additional DIV for the first article in your template override. 
A pure CSS solution would be to use the :first-child selector to change the appearance of the first article (without adding an extra DIV).

Comment: thanks for your response. Yeah I am using chronological order. Well but if I use an template override for an article than there is no such loop? .. because there's only one article displayed.

Comment: You might compare your case with one of the template overrides from the the default installation, e.g. templates/beez5/html/com_content/category/ If you use the category blog display, check out blog.php. There are a couple of foreach loops. They call the item view (only once if there is only one item to display)