# Joomla Article add custom Options

Tags: xml, layout, joomla, joomla1.6

I am trying to add extra fields to the Backend page of Joomla-Articles. Because I want to use them in my layout override. Therefore I tried to change parameters in:

```
/html/components/com_content/views/article/tmpl/default.xml
```

Now my questions:

1. Why are there no changes visible, when changing anything in this file?
2. Is it possible to overrite this xml-file with an Joomla layout-overwrite in my Template?
3. I only want to display this fields to Articles of an custom category. Is this possible? (Maybe via extended layout overwrite?)

Thanks for your help guys, 
Ripei

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameters in that XML files only determine the parameters that are displayed in the menu item associated with the relate view. In order to add additional fields to articles you are going to either hack the core or use a CCK type extension. Unfortunately, I don't think any of the CCK extensions have been release for 1.6 yet. I know several are in the works and jSeblod 2.0 for Joomla 1.6 was supposed to be released last week but doesn't appear to be available yet.

http://www.jseblod-cck.com/

Comment: Thanks for also providing an answer to this question Brent. As for now this seems to be the current best answer to this question... and btw. I already resolved this with adapting the xml via the custom menu-item-layout - just for somebody reading this, her is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5795799/joomla-custom-template-override-not-working/5797024#5797024

Comment: That's an interesting use of the alternate layouts, very clever. FYI depending on your needs, it may be worth looking in to Joomla 1.5 with one of the mature CCKs, very powerful and much easier than forcing 1.6 to do it the hard way.