# Joomla Template Overrides Ignored When itemid in URL

Tags: joomla, joomla-template

question on template overrides.

I have created several custom categories, and have duplicated the category 'default.php' and named it 'video.php' and just added a piece of text to check it. Now if I got to the page via the menu, it adds an itemid to the URL and that causes the override NOT to work, if I remove the itemID then it works...?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this: [Joomla custom Template Override not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5795799/joomla-custom-template-override-not-working)

Note the part about **alternatelayout.xml**

Then this: http://docs.joomla.org/Layout_Overrides_in_Joomla_2.5

Everything is documented well.

Comment: Thank you so much, I had never came across that before I did not know that was a thing! Wow Googling fail ;)